# Is there a way to remove the effect of "<center>...</center>" tag for a particular element?

Tags: html, css

Consider following HTML snippet,

```
<center>
   <input type="text" id="one">
   <input type="text" id="two">
   <a href="#" id="three">Hyperlink</a>
   <input type="text" id="four">
</center>
```

As shown above, because of the "`<center>...</center>`" tag, everything will be center aligned. However, I don't want the center aligned property for the HTML element with "id=three" i.e. the hyperlink. Is there a way through which I can achieve this? Alternate suggestions for similar design are also welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Step 1: Don't use the `<center>` element. It was deprecated in HTML4 and removed in HTML5.

Comment: @j08691 I agree that it is deprecated, but c'mon even Google uses this tag. There has to be some way around.

Comment: you have to use `text-align:left` for the `<center>` tag, and then check and override any other tags that may still be aligned center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in comments `<center>` element was deprecated in HTML4 and removed in HTML5.

But if you still want to use it, you can try this:

```
a#three {
 text-align: left;
 display:block;
}
```

Check this **[example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myxWYe)**.

Answer (score 0):

1) Center tag is not supported in HTML 5, [Look Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)
 
2)If you still want to, you can use `float:left`, See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mihiruj/7dLfg167/1/) here

Comment: (1) Doesn't answer the question. (2) Use it how? External links shouldn't be required reading for an answer to a question like this. Your external link left aligns all the text inputs as well as the link. The question is asking how to left align *only* the link.